# MYSQL Connector not connecting

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this code atm in c# and the MYSQL connection wont work:

```
int chk;
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=sql9.freemysqlhosting.net;port=3306;Initial Catalog=new;UserId=sql9FFFFF9;password=X3FFFFYX8;");
con.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from sql9164489.users where username='" + txt_user.Text + "' and password='" + txt_pass.Text + "'";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
chk = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
//If Correct
if (chk == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Connected");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");
}
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

con.Opern() raises an error:

> Authentication to host 'sql9.freemysqlhosting.net' for user 'sql9FFFFF9' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'sql9FFFFF9'@'188.244.39.23' (using password: YES)

I guess it's pretty clear

Answer (score 0):

Download MySQL connector for .net and your working will be more easy as database will display in server explorer and then you can copy and paste the connection string from there.
[Here is link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/)